# Dynamically add sender email to Message Header rule in Outlook 2007 via right-click

Tags: vba, outlook, rules, outlook-2007

I would like VBA code for Outlook 2007 to right-click a message in any mail view, choose a rule to add it to, and have the sender email be added to the Message Header contains value for that rule.

Only particular rules use Message Header as a criteria, so only those applicable rules should show when I right-click a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little effort, you are able to [manipulate the context menu with VBA](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=314).

Any Outlook version prior to 2007 has no object model for rules.

But since OL2007, each Store object exposes GetRules() method, which returns a Rules collection. Try to iterate that collection and fill a CommandBarPopup object with all the rules you want. The Rule objects can be manipulated, so in theory you should be able to do the job.